# Do aliases need to have unique names in mysql union

Tags: mysql, sql

I've done the following, and haven't seemed to experienced any problems.  Is it improper to use the same alias in different queries combined with a UNION?

```
SELECT table1.a,t.b,t.c
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t ON t.table1_id=table1.id
WHERE t.fk=123
SELECT table2.a,t.b,t.c
UNION
FROM table3
INNER JOIN table4 AS t ON t.table3_id=table3.id
WHERE t.fk=123;
```

Comment: I think that query does not work. But no for the UNION and aliases but sintaxis: `WHERE ... SELECT ... UNION` should be `WHERE ... UNION SELECT ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The separate parts of a `union` are treated as separate subqueries.  You can use the same alias for tables in both, so there is no problem with the query as you have written it.  The names for the columns come from the first subquery in the `union`, regardless of the names in subsequent subqueries.

This is true of MySQL and other databases as well.

Answer (score 1):

No it's fine. Those queries have different scopes, so it will work.

But this, for instance won't:

```
select *
from
  Table1 a
  inner join Table2 a  ....
```

Now you try to introduce two times the alias 'a' into the same scope.

Rule of thumb: If you are doing something that isn't allowed: MySQL will tell you. If it works, then it is fine. Simple as that. :)